# moment.js does not convert timestamps with specific timezones to unix timestamps

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js to convert a bunch of timestamps in it's specific timezone to a unix timestamp like this:

```
var timestamp = "2015-12-29T09:35:00.000-08:00";
console.log(moment("2015-12-29T09:35:00.000-08:00").unix();
console.log(moment("2015-12-29T09:35:00.000-08:00").tz("America/Los_Angeles").unix();
```

The console log of both the above statements is for some reason, the same - 1451361900. This unix timestamp which it is logging is in my local timezone and not the one I asked for: "America/Los_Angeles". What am I missing?

Comment: unix or posix format does not have concept of timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to use **moment-Timezone** is this.

```
console.log(moment("2015-12-29T09:35:00").unix());
console.log(moment.tz("2015-12-29T09:35" , "America/Los_Angeles").unix());
```

In above your are providing time zone as a string too which is this last part ".000-08:00" and then you are providing another zone, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

A unix timestamp, or Posix, should always be in the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) format.

Moment is just doing something like

```
function unix () {
    return Math.floor(+this / 1000);
}
```

Where it converts the date object to an integer and then converts from milliseconds to seconds.

The starting point is a regular javascript Date object, and the ECMA standard says

> Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
>   milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

so date objects are always UTC when converted to the number of milliseconds since 1. January 1970 (epoch), i.e. you can't set another timezone on a Unix timestamp, both your dates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to find out the unix timestamp for the date "**2015-12-29T09:35:00.000-08:00**". In this date format timezone value is already present which is "**-08:00**", hence you get the same unix timestamp.

For getting the unix timestamp desired solution, remove the timezone value and use moment-timezone as :

> console.log(moment.tz("2013-12-01", "America/Los_Angeles").unix());

For more details check [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)